# Codepen vs Bootstrap: CSS behaves differently

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, codepen

I'm trying to fit texts to divs of various size that are themselves responsive thanks to viewport units.

Here is the problem: the code below is working fine in one codepen, at least for the four examples that I have: https://codepen.io/gramm/pen/VJPavg

The text fits the div and does not overflow when the page is resized. However, when I have the exact same HTML and CSS on my page, which uses Bootstrap 4, I get text overflowing.

**EDIT**: actually, it worked fine in Firefox 60.7.1(esr). After update to 60.7.2(esr), text is overflowing also in codepen. It is overflowing in Edge as well...

[Codepen: no overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6OPr.png)

[Bootstrap page: overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzbU1.png)

Does anyone know what can be the cause of this behavior? Is it something in Bootstrap that prevents the same display as in Codepen? Or is it something in Codepen's CSS that is missing from my page?

```css
.text {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#tm12901 {
  width: 15.952380952380954vh;
  height: 50vh;
  font-size: 0.8vh;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background: Pink;
}

#tm56 {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 12.873563218390805vw;
  font-size: 0.525vw;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: flex;
  background: LightCyan;
}

#tm242 {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 21.333333333333336vw;
  font-size: 0.875vw;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: flex;
  background: Beige;
}

#tm9135 {
  width: 36.58536585365854vh;
  height: 50vh;
  font-size: 1.35vh;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: flex;
  background: PaleGreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="tm12901" class="text">
    <span class="ab">Ἀπολλωνίωι βασιλικ(ῶι) <br id="al2">γραμματεῖ Ἀρσι(νοίτου) Θεμίστο(υ) <br id="al3">παρὰ Θερμίου τῆς Σατα-<br id="al4">βοῦτος τῶν ἀπὸ κ(ώμ)ης <br id="al5">Σεντρεπασ̣εὶ τῆς αὐτῆς <br id="al6">μερίδος μετὰ κυρίου &lt;τοῦ&gt; συν-<br id="al7">γενοῦς Πνεφερῶτος <br id="al8">τοῦ Ἀρείου. ὁ προγεγραμ(μένος) <br id="al9">μου πατὴρ Σαταβοῦς <br id="al10">Πανίβιος μητρὸς <br id="al11">Ταρμούθιος ὑπερετὴς <br id="al12">ἀναγραφόμενος ἐπὶ τῆς <br id="al13">αὐτῆς κ(ώμ)ης ἐτελεύτη-<br id="al14">σεν τῶι Θὼθ μηνὶ τοῦ <br id="al15">ἐνεστῶτος πρώτου <br id="al16">καὶ εἰκοστοῦ (ἔτους) Ἁδριανοῦ <br id="al17">Καίσαρος τοῦ κυρίου. ἀξιῶι <br id="al18">ταγῆναι αὐτοῦ τὸ ὄνο-<br id="al19">μα ἐν τῇ τῶν τετελευτηκότ(ων) <br id="al20">τάξει ὡς ἐπὶ τῶν ὁμοίω(ν). <br>—— <br id="al21">Θέρμιον ὡς (ἐτῶν) <span title="number: 49">μθ</span>    οὐλ(ὴ) δακ(τύλῳ) (πρώτῳ) χ(ειρὸς) <span class="gap" lang="en">[...]</span> <br id="al22">Πνεφερῶς ὡς (ἐτῶν) <span title="number: 45">με</span> οὐλ(ὴ) δακ(τύλῳ) χ(ειρὸς) ἀρισ(τερᾶς). <br id="al23">(ἔτους) <span title="number: 21">κα</span> Αὐτοκραρος
    <br id="al24">Τραιανοῦ Ἁδριανοῦ Σεβαστοῦ <br id="al25">Φαῶφι <span title="number: 29">κ̣θ</span>. <br id="al26">(hand 2) τῶι κωμογρα(μματεῖ). εἰ ταῖς ἀληθ(είαις) <br id="al27">ἐτελ(εύτησεν) ὁ προγεγρα(μμένος), ἐπιτέλ(ει) ὡς καθ(ήκει), <br id="al28">ὡς πρὸς σὲ τοῦ λόγου <br id="al29">ἐσομένου, ἐάν τι παρὰ <br id="al30">τὸ δέον γένη(ται). (hand 3) Ἀνουβίω(ν) γρα(μματεὺς) σεση(μείωμαι). <br id="al31">(hand 2) (ἔτους) <span title="number: 21">κα</span> Ἁδριανοῦ Καίσαρος <br id="al32">τοῦ κυρίου Ἁθὺρ
    <span title="number: 6">ϛ</span>. <br id="al33">(hand 4) Θερις Σαταβος ὑπό-<br id="al34">μνημα. (ἔτους) <span title="number: 21">κα</span> <br id="al35">Ἁθρὺ <span title="number: 7">ζ</span>. </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="tm56" class="text">
    <span class="ab">(ἔτους) <span title="number: 4">δ</span> Μεσορὴ <span title="number: 11">ια</span>. ἀπέδοτο <br id="a1-l2">Ταθῶτις πήχεις στερε(οῦ) <br id="a1-l3"><span title="number: 5">ε</span> (ἀφʼ ὧν(?)) Ταελολοῦς <span title="number: 3">γ</span>    <br id="a1-l4">Πετεαρσεμθεὺς <span title="number: 2">β</span> (γίνονται) <span title="number: 5">ε</span> <br id="a1-l5">χα(λκοῦ) <span title="number: 5000">Ε</span>. </span><span class="ab">βασιλευόντων Κλεοπάτρας καὶ βασιλέως Πτολεμα[ί]ου θεῶν Φιλομητόρων Σωτήρων <br id="a2-l2">ἔτους <span title="number: 6">ϛ</span>    ἐφ ἱερείως βασιλέως Πτολεμαίου θεοῦ Φιλομήτορος Σωτῆρος Ἀλεξάνδρου καὶ <br id="a2-l3">θεῶν Σωτήρων καὶ θεῶν Ἀδελφῶν καὶ θεῶν Εὐεργετῶν καὶ θεῶν Φιλοπατόρων καὶ <br id="a2-l4">θεῶν Ἐπιφανῶν καὶ θεοῦ Εὐπάτορος καὶ θεοῦ Φιλομήτορος καὶ θεοῦ Φιλοπάτορος
    νέου καὶ <br id="a2-l5">θεοῦ Εὐεργέτου καὶ θεῶν Φιλομητόρων Σωτήρων ἱερουπώλου Ἴσιδος μεγάλης <br id="a2-l6">μητρὸς θεῶν ἀθλοφόρου Βερενίκης Εὐεργέτιδος κα[ν]ηφόρου Ἀρσινόης Φιλαδέλφου <br id="a2-l7">ἱερε[ί]ας Ἀρσινόης Φιλοπάτορος τῶν ὄντων ἐν Ἀλεξαν[δ]ρείαι,
    <br id="a2-l8">ἐν δὲ Πτολεμαίδι τῆς Θηβαίδος ἐφʼ εἱρειων καὶ ἱερισσ[ῶ]ν καὶ κανηφόρου τῶν ὄντων <br id="a2-l9">καὶ οὐσσῶν ἐν Πτολεμαίδι μηνὸς Παῦνι <span title="number: 11">ια</span> ἐν Παθύρει [ἐ]φʼ Ἡλιοδώρου ἀγορανόμου. <br id="a2-l10">ἀπέδοτο Ταθῶτις
    Φίβιος Περσίνη ὡς (ἐτῶν) <span title="number: 50">ν</span> μέση μ[ε]λίχρως μακροπρόσωπος <br id="a2-l11">εὐθύριν μετὰ κυρίου τοῦ ἑαυτῆς πρεσβυτέρου υἱοῦ Πατσεοῦτος το[ῦ Πα]τῆτος Πέρσου <br id="a2-l12">τῆς ἐπιγονῆς ἀπὸ τοῦ ὑπάρχοντος αὐτῇ ψιλοῦ τόπου
    τοῦ ὄντ[ος ἐ]ν τῷ ἀπὸ λι(βὸς) </span><span class="ab">μέρει Παθύρεως πήχεις στερεοῦ <span title="number: 5">ε</span> [ἐ]ν τῷ ἀπὸ βορρᾶ <br id="a3-l2">μέρει γείτονες τούτων· νότου τῆς αὐτῆς ψιλὸς τόπος <br id="a3-l3">βορρᾶ οἰκία Σεννήσιος ἀπηλιώτου
    ὁδὸς λι(βὸς) ψιλὸς τόπος <br id="a3-l4">τοῦ ἱεροῦ ἢ οἳ ἂν ὦσιν γείτονες. ἐπρίατο Ταελολοῦς Τοτοητις <br id="a3-l5">καὶ Πετεαρσεμθεὺς Πανοβχούνιος, ἀφʼ ὧν Ταελολοῦς <span title="number: 3">γ</span> <br id="a3-l6">Πετεαρσεμθεὺς πήχεις δύο (γίνονται)
    πή(χεις) <span title="number: 5">ε</span> χα(λκοῦ) <span title="number: 5000">Ε</span>. προπωλη-<br id="a3-l7">τρία καὶ βεβαιωτρία Ταθῶτις ἡ ἀποδομένη, ἣν ἐδέ-<br id="a3-l8">ξαντο Ταελολοῦς καὶ Πετεαρσεμθεὺς οἱ πριάμενοι. <br>—— <br id="a3-l9">Ἀμμώ(νιος)
    ὁ παρὰ Σώσου κεχρη(μάτικα). <br id="a3-l10">ἔτους <span title="number: 4">δ</span> Μεσορὴ <span title="number: 30">λ</span> τέ(τακται) ἐπὶ τ[ὴ]ν ἐν Κρο(κοδίλων) πό(λει) τρά(πεζαν) ἐφʼ ἧς Ἀπολλώνιος [θέμα] <br id="a3-l11">(δεκάτης) ἐγκυ(κλίου) κατὰ
    τὴν παρὰ Πανίσκου τ[ο]ῦ τελώνου διαγρα(φὴν) ὑφʼ ἣν ὑπ[ογρά(φει)] <br id="a3-l12">Ἀπολλώ(νιος) ὁ ἀντιγρα(φεὺς) Ταελολοῦς Τοτοήτ(ιος) καὶ Πετεαρσεμ(θεὺς) Πανοβχού[ν(ιος)] <br id="a3-l13">ψιλοῦ τόπου π(ήχεων) <span title="number: 5">ε</span> ἐν Πα̣θ̣ύ(ρει)
    ἀφʼ ὧν Ταελολοῦς π(ήχεις) [<span title="number: 3">γ</span> καὶ] Πετεαρσεμ(θεὺς) π(ήχεις) <span title="number: 2">β</span>, <br id="a3-l14">ὃν ἠγόρα(σαν) παρὰ Ταθώτιος τῆς Φίβιος χα(λκοῦ) <span title="number: 5000">Ε</span> τέλ(ος) <span title="number: 500">φ</span>    <br id="a3-l15">Ἀπολλώ(νιος) τρα(πεζίτης) <span title="number: 600">χ</span></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="tm242" class="text">
    <span class="ab">ἔτους <span title="number: 15">ιε</span> τοῦ καὶ <span title="number: 12">ιβ</span> <br id="a1-l2">Ἁθὺρ <span title="number: 11">ια</span>. ἀπέδοτο <br id="a1-l3">Ψενμεγχῆς Πανεχά(του) <br id="a1-l4">οἰκίαν ᾠκοδο(μημένην) καὶ ἐσ-
    <br
      id="a1-l5"><span class="linenumber">5</span>τεγασμένην κεκα-<br id="a1-l6">μαρω(μένην) καὶ τὴν προσοῦσαν <br id="a1-l7">ἀ\ου/υλὴν ἐν τῇ μέσῃ ται-<br id="a1-l8">νίᾳ Παθύ(ρεως). ἐπρίατο <br id="a1-l9">Ψενενοῦ(πις) Πασᾶτος <br id="a1-l10">χα(λκοῦ) (τάλαντα)
      <span
        title="number: 3">γ</span> (δραχμὰς) <span title="number: 2000">Β</span>. </span><span class="ab">ἀντίγρα(φον) ὠνῆς. <br id="a2-l2">βασιλευόντων Κλεοπάτρας καὶ Πτολεμαίου ἐπικαλουμένου Ἀλεξάνδρου τοῦ υ[ἱ]οῦ θεῶν Φι[λομητ]όρων <br id="a2-l3">ἔτους <span title="number: 15">ιε</span>        τοῦ καὶ <span title="number: 12">ιβ</span> ἐφʼ ἱερείων καὶ ἱερειῶν καὶ κανηφόρου τῶν ὄντων καὶ οὐσῶν μη[νὸ]ς Ἁθὺρ <span title="number: 11">ι[α</span> ἐν Πα]θύρε[ι] <br id="a2-l4">ἐφʼ Ἑρμίου τοῦ παρὰ Πανίσκου ἀγορανόμου. ἀπέδοτο Ψενμεγχῆς Πανεχάτ[ο]υ
        Πέρσης τ[ῆς ἐπι]γονῆς <br id="a2-l5">ὡς ἐτῶν <span title="number: 40">μ</span> μέσος μελίχρω(ς) τετανὸς ἀναφάλακρος μακροπρόσω(πος) εὐθύριν ἐπισχάζων τὸν πόδα δεξιὸν [ο]ὐλὴ παρʼ <br id="a2-l6">ὀφθαλμὸν ἀριστερὸν τὴν ὑπαρχον αὐτῶι οἰκίαν ᾠκοδομημένην
        καὶ ἐστεγασμένην καὶ κεκαμαρω[μ]ένην <br id="a2-l7">καὶ τεθυρωμένην καὶ τὴν προσοῦσαν αὐλὴν τὴν οὖσαν ἐν τῇ μέσῃ ταινίᾳ Παθύρεω[ς] ἧς γείτονε[ς νότου ο]ἰκία <br id="a2-l8">Νεχούτου τοῦ Πανεχάτου βορρᾶ οἰκία Κεφάλωνος ἀπηλιώτου ῥύμη λιβὸς οἰκία
        Πόρτ[ι]τ[ος] τοῦ Πε[τεσούχ]ου καὶ <br id="a2-l9">ἀνὰ μέσον ῥύμη ἢ οἳ ἂν ὦσι γείτονες πάντοθεν. ἐπρίατο Ψενενοῦπις Πασᾶτος Πέρσης ὡς (ἐτῶν) <span title="number: 50">ν</span> χαλ[κοῦ τά]λαντα <br id="a2-l10">τρία δραχμὰς δισχιλίας . προπωλητὴς καὶ
        βεβαιωτὴς τῶν κατὰ τὴν ὠνὴν ταύτην πάντων Ψ[ενμεγ]χῆς <br id="a2-l11">ὁ ἀποδόμενος, ὃν ἐδέξατο Ψενενοῦπις ὁ πριάμενος. </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text" id="tm9135">
    <span class="ab"> Μαξίμῳ στρατηγῶι Ἀ[ρσι]νοείτ(ου) Ἡρακλείδο(υ) μερίδος καὶ <br id="ar-l2">Ἡρακλείδῃ βασιλικ(ῷ) γραμματ(εῖ) τῆς αὐτῆς μερίδος καὶ <br id="ar-l3">Ὀρσενούφι κωμογραμματ(εῖ) Καρανίδος καὶ <br id="ar-l4">Διοσκόρῳ καὶ τοῖς λοιποῖς λαογράφοις τῆς αὐτῆ(ς) κώμης <br id="ar-l5">παρὰ Πεθέως τοῦ Πεθέως τοῦ Πνεφερῶτο(ς) (μητρὸς) Ταμύσθας <br id="ar-l6">ἀπὸ κώμης Καρανίδο(ς). κατὰ τὰ κελευσθέντα ἀπογρά-<br id="ar-l7">φομαι ἐμαυτόν τε καὶ τοὺς ἐμοὺς εἰς τὴν τοῦ <br id="ar-l8">διεληλυθότος ἐνάτου (ἔτους) Ἀντωνίνου Καίσαρος τοῦ κυρίου <br id="ar-l9">κατʼ οἰκίαν ἀπογραφὴν εἰς τὴν ὑπ[άρχ]ουσαν τῇ γυ-<br id="ar-l10">[ναικί] μου Ἀφροδοῦτι Ἄπιτος ἐν τῇ κώμῃ οἰκίαν καὶ <br id="ar-l11">[αὐλ]ὴν οὖσαν ἐπʼ ἀμφόδου Κωμογραμματέων. <br id="ar-l12">εἰμὶ δὲ <br id="ar-l13">[Πεθεὺς] ὁ προγεγραμμένος ἀπολελυμένος τῆς λαογραφείας  <br id="ar-l14">(ἐτῶν) <span title="number: 76">οϛ</span>    ο[ὐλ]ὴ ποδὶ δεξ[ι]ῷ, καὶ γυναῖκά μου Ἀφροδοῦν <br id="ar-l15">Ἄ[πιτο]ς τοῦ Παπ[ο]ντῶτος (ἐτῶν) <span title="number: 70">ο</span> οὐλὴ γόνατει δεξιῷ <br id="ar-l16">καὶ [τὴν ἐ]ξ ἀμφοτέρων θυγατέρα Δι[οδ]ώραν (ἐτῶν) <span title="number: 33">λγ</span>    ἄσημο(ν) <br id="ar-l17">καὶ τὰ ἐξ αὐτῆς τ[έκνα] θ[ηλ]υκὰ τρία , ἅπερ ἀπε-<br id="ar-l18">γράψατο ὁ πατὴρ <span class="gap" lang="en">[&nbsp;&nbsp;̣&nbsp;&nbsp;̣&nbsp;&nbsp;̣&nbsp;&nbsp;̣&nbsp;&nbsp;̣]</span>ς Π[ε]θέως διὰ ἑτέρου κολλήματ[ος]
    <br
      id="ar-l19">ὑπάρχι δὲ τ[ῇ θυγατρὶ] παιδίσκη δούλη Τασου[χάρ]ιον <br id="ar-l20">(ἐτῶν) <span title="number: 32">λβ</span> ἄσημ[ος, ὑπάρχει δὲ] καὶ τῇ Ἀφροδοῦτι ο̣[ἰκία <span class="gap" lang="en">&nbsp;&nbsp;̣&nbsp;&nbsp;̣&nbsp;&nbsp;̣]</span> <br id="ar-l21">κωι
      ψιλὸς τόπ[ος.] <br id="ar-l22">(hand 2) Πε<span class="gap" lang="en">[&nbsp;&nbsp;̣&nbsp;&nbsp;̣&nbsp;&nbsp;̣]</span>χ σεση(μείωμαι). <br id="ar-l23">(hand 3) Ἀπολ[λ(ώνιος)] σεση(μείωμαι). <br id="ar-l24">(hand 1) (ἔτους) <span title="number: 10">ι</span>      Ἀντωνίνου [Καί]σαρος τοῦ κυρίου Ἐπεὶφ <span title="number: 30"><span class="supraline" title="line above">λ</span></span>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FWIW, your CodePen link has it overflowing for me.

Comment: CodePen example also overflows here.

Comment: So I guess I was just lucky with my version of Firfox :(

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap pretty much requires that you put a `<div class="row">` inside your container.  There's a pseudo-element on `.row` that clears the float after all content, which is the root of your issue.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="tm242" class="text">
                <!-- all of your content -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Second problem is that you have a fixed height on the div `#tm242`.  It appears that 21.33vw simply isn't tall enough for your text.  Remove that fixed height and let bootstrap do the work of calculating that height for you.

Comment: There is already a `<div class="row">` you can see it on the second image link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzbU1.png)

Comment: @gramm There's no `div class="row"` in your code here in your question or in the CodePen link.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes that's right I don't have a row div in the codepen (since it was working I thought it was a problem with my own page). I can't just remove the fixed height: one of the constraint I have is that the div must respect some precise aspect ratio, and the div height is calculated for that purpose. But  it seems it was working in codepen only by luck. I just updated firefox and now I have text overflowing!